# Scale WebView in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, webview, scale

How can I scale the content of a WebView?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call `-scaleUnitSquareToSize:` on the document view of the individual frame that you want to resize, for example the main frame:

```
[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(1.5, 1.5)];
[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Comment: This leads to the content being clipped on the right at 1/1.5 (i.e. 2/3) of the view's bounds, just like the comments on the answer by @Wanderer confirm. Scaling the documentView's superView doesn't work either, because then the mouse pointer does not work correcty (as also stated in the other answer's comments). So, neither of the answers here work for me so far (on 10.10.5)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010634/zooming-in-and-out-in-webview-cocoa

Answer (score 5):

Or you can try the following:

```
- (IBAction)takeZoom:(NSSlider *)sender {
    WebView *aWebView = [[window.contentView subviews] lastObject];
    NSView *clipView = [[[[aWebView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview];
    float scale = pow( 4, [sender floatValue] )/(clipView.frame.size.width/clipView.bounds.size.width);
    [clipView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(scale, scale)];
    [clipView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: Setting the scale in the clip view appears to be the correct way to do this. I'm too tired to hit this hard, but Rob's suggestion above does scale, but also leaves enlarges the scroll content area, so you get a scaled page, but an 'artifacts playground' of broken pixels at the right side of the web view. I just pulled out lines 2,4,5 of the above routine and that appears to work. My report view is scaled to a web view in a dialog panel. Thanks Wanderer!

Comment: This works great for me! The accepted answer would get clipped off inappropriately.

Comment: You're both finding scaling the documentView's superview to scale perfectly? I'm seeing clipping on the right & incorrect reflow. Are you scaling just once, or repeatedly, as in zoom in & out buttons under user control? scaleUnitSquareToSize doesn't work as one might expect in this circumstance, I finally found this Apple Q&A which shed some light https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1346.html but something still isn't right. Using the category there, I'm using essentially: clipView=[documentView superview]; clipView.scale=NSMakeSize(scale,scale); clipView.needsDisplay=YES;

Comment: This looks fine, but selections in the WebView are offset relative to the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is your bestfriend:

```
 [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.zoom = \"0.5\""];
```

Answer (score -2):

A WebView is an NSView, so one way would be [to send it a `scaleUnitSquareToSize:` message](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/scaleUnitSquareToSize:).

Comment: Because a WebView is actually a fairly complex set of managed nested views, you actually can't just call `-scaleUnitSquareToSize:` on the main `WebView` object.