# Webkit page scaling in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit

I'm making a WebKit-based text editor app for Mac, and I need to find a way to zoom the document in and out.

I've seen this StackOverflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181587/scale-webview-in-cocoa), it suggests just scaling the view that Webkit is rendered into. The problem is, since Webkit doesn't know about it, this breaks things like drag & drop and causes Javascript to report the wrong cursor locations. Unfortunately, for some reason, the Cocoa WebKit API only supports scaling text up or down, not the whole page.

Safari and Chrome are both able to do this properly. I've gone as far as to look through the Chromium source code to figure out how it's done, but unfortunately it's using a completely different cross-platform API.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not opposed to using private APIs, if I can figure out how to use them in a safe way.

-Keaton

Comment: WebKit.framework is open source too, not too hard to dig through and find the pirate API for this

Answer (score 4):

The APIs for doing this aren't currently public, but they've been around for years and aren't likely to change. You can find them in WebKit's [`WebViewPrivate.h` header](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebViewPrivate.h?rev=151535#L210). You won't find that header on your system, so you'll have to redeclare those methods yourself in a category. Something like:

```
@interface WebView (Zoom)
- (IBAction)zoomPageIn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)zoomPageOut:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)resetPageZoom:(id)sender;
@end
```

Another option is just to set the CSS `zoom` property on the `html` element in your editor. You can do that in markup (`<html style="zoom: 1.5">`) or in JavaScript (`document.documentElement.style.zoom = "1.5"`). That doesn't require using any private APIs.

Comment: [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.zoom = \"0.5\""]; is the best solution.

Comment: Using stringByEvaluatingJavascript will not work if Javascript is disabled for webview. Hence adding a category would be a better option.