# Scale html content in Webview

Tags: macos, safari, webview

I load a local HTML template into a `WebView`. My webview's frame size is very small (250X300). I use this to show only a preview. The problem is, I can't see the entire html content in the webview. I can see only the top left. I have to scroll to see the entire content. 
So is there any possiblity to set the scale or zoom factor for the webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer after a little play around.

```
    [[[[[previewWeb mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(.5, .5)];
```

Comment: use this method I found web view did scale but mouse selection position has offset...

Comment: I agree with Tinyfool - See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181587/scale-webview-in-cocoa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010634/zooming-in-and-out-in-webview-cocoa

Answer (score 2):

If it is good enough for you to zoom text only, then use the methods `-[WebView makeTextSmaller:]` and `-[WebView makeTextLarger:]` and to reset the text size `-[WebView makeTextStandardSize:]` as documented for `WebView`. These methods correspond to "Cmd -" and "Cmd +" and "Cmd 0" in Safari.

If you want to scale the whole content of a WebView including images I use the following method:

```
- (void) zoomWebView:(WebView *)aWebView withFactor:(float)fac
{
    NSString *script = @"document.body.style.zoom";
    float oldFac = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script] floatValue];
    if( oldFac==0 ){ oldFac = 1.0; }
    NSString *res = [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@='%1.2f';", script, (oldFac*fac)]];
    [aWebView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: It is partially working. It is not zooming entire content properly. It is zooming some contents perfectly, but some contents are not zooming a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undocumented

```
- (void)_setZoomMultiplier:(float)m isTextOnly:(BOOL)isTextOnly
```

**Note** : That this may cause problems with submissions to the App Store.