# Zooming in and out in WebView Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

Below is my code:

```
[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(1.5,1.5)]; 
[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Ok it work, webView did scale, but **mouse selection position has offset**.

[Image example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7olm019t6s0poio/ok.png)

How to fix it???

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181587/scale-webview-in-cocoa

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access the documentView?

```
[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(1.5,1.5)];
```

works as well.

Comment: This resize also the scrollView, I want to resize only the content