# Scaling WebView content makes it look blurry

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, scaling

I'm try to make a program for the Mac that uses a WebView to display some HTML code. I need to scale the web content down to fully fit the screen horizontally (I don't care about vertically). To do this I have implemented the method:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame{
    if([webFrame isEqual:[self.webView mainFrame]]){

        //scale page to correct size
        NSRect webFrameRect = [[[webFrame frameView] documentView] frame];
        float scale = ([[[[self.webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview].frame.size.width) / webFrameRect.size.width;

        [[[[[self.webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview] scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(scale, scale)];
        [[[[[self.webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview] setNeedsDisplay:YES];

        self.webView.alphaValue = 1;

    }//end if
}//end method
```

And this method of scaling is working correctly but the problem is that any text loaded now looks blurry. Is there any way to make the text sharper after scaling the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Several answers were given here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192385/scale-html-content-in-webview/13193121#13193121

Comment: That only says how to zoom, which I am already doing fine. The problem is that the text looks blurry after zooming.