# Mac OS X / Cocoa - disable WebView image scaling on Retina display

Tags: cocoa, webview, scaling, retina-display

I am using a WebView control in my Cocoa/OS X application to display screenshots. I'm just loading the JPEG image directly to a WebView as a document. It works OK with a non-Retina screen, but in HiDPI mode the WebView is automatically scaling the loaded image up, and that's not what I need. I just need to display it as is, pixel-by-pixel. I've spent half of the day searching the web regarding how to change that WebView behavior easily and for some reason had no success.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the scaling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181587/scale-webview-in-cocoa

Comment: Yes I tried that, the problem is I'll need to scale it down and then back again for every content type (text or image), also the multiple calls to scaleUnitSquareToSize are dangerous, because it changes scale again and again on every call. Maybe I can do what I need with this type of scaling, but it's looking like overkill and error-prone for my task. It's strange there is no simple way just to tell WebView NOT to scale the loaded image. Although there are some guides with CSS tweaking and Retina display, most of them are for mobiles and not for desktop.

Comment: Apple provides some brief guide regarding the image scaling for Retina display and desktop browser, but I was unable to use it for my task.
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012449-CH3-SW1

Comment: I've finally found a simple way to do what I need.. It's enough to apply  style="zoom: 0.5"  attribute to the IMG html tag in Retina mode to display it correctly. Together with loadHTMLString method of WebFrame it took just a few lines of code to fix my issue.