# Disabling NSView automatic scaling on retina displays

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am using CGContextDrawImage to draw an image to NSView and that's working fine,  but on HiDPI (retina) screens NSView get automatically 2X bigger and that makes image stretched and pixelated. My question is how to disable that automatic scaling?

Comment: To get any kind of in-depth help here, you're going to need to post your code. If I had to suggest something off the top of my head, I'd recommend using a higher-level drawing API, like one of NSImage's drawing methods, instead of CGContextDrawImage, since they tend to automagically handle the hi-res displays (assuming, of course, that you have both normal and 2x versions of your image, as you should).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The image is not the problem. It's size is handled automatically on HiDPI screens. Image is part of the framework where all GUI scaling and view size is handled automatically. The problem is that if I resize to 1000x1000px view I actually get 2000x2000px view. Now I can resize view to 500x500px to get 1000x1000px but that screws my mouse handling methods, so it would be ideal if view can just stay the same. Also I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623783/mac-os-x-cocoa-disable-webview-image-scaling-on-retina-display

Comment: I wonder if I can change zoom on NSView...

Comment: On HiDPI screens, the points you pass to the various drawing methods actually are 2 pixels wide each, so this is normal. Again, it's hard to help much more if you don't post your code.

Comment: See this topic.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/97445#97445